# When I add an item to a listbox from a separate listbox, how do I find the string from the item added and search for that string within a text file?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am working on an online shopping cart application and am quite new to Visual Basic 2010. I have two listbox's one for the current items in stock and another for the cart. When a user clicks an item in stock it is added to the second list box, how do I find the string of this item added so that I can then search for it within a text file and finds its cost using an array of records?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Can you please state the platform in which you are using VB so that the solution can be an appropriate one.

Comment: i don't quite get it.. what's inside the "stock" list box?? is the "cart" list box empty at first? where to find the cost?? is it given?? is there a database involved?? please be more specific

Comment: Sorry, I'm also new to this forum. I am using Visual Basic 2010 express and yes, the 'Cart' listbox is empty to start with until the user doubleclicks an item in the 'Stock' listbox (holding 30 items so far) where it is then added to the 'Cart'. The cost is given within the string of the item and I am using a text file with a record structure to hold the Food Name and the Food Cost.

Comment: There is also seperate code to read the textfile and then find the values which works fine, however I can not search the textfile with the correct string as I'm not sure how to find it form the item added into the 'Cart' listbox